# Unable to try Instagram API media search with sandbox account

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to run the media search using my sandbox account.

request url: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=<my_AT>`

I get this response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
    "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."
  }
}
```

My understanding is that I have to use the sandbox account until my site is production ready, but it is not.  How can I test this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to authenticate with `public_content` scope and then you will not get that error and will get sandbox mode API response